# Get or Retrieve Generated PKs after a massive insert SQLLDR

Tags: java, sql, weblogic, oracle12c, sql-loader

I'll be direct about my situation right now. I'm working in a project which will perform a "Base load" procedure based on an excel (xlsx, xls) file. It has been developed in java with JDBC drivers. right  now this project is working, It takes an excel file and based on a configuration It performances the insert into differents tables. The point is: It's taking too long doing the job, which makes it inefficient. (It takes around 2 hours inserting 3000 records on DB). in the future, this software will be inserted around 30k records and it will be painfully slow. So I need to improve its efficience and I was thinking in: Instead of inserting from java via JDBC drivers. I will generate control files and data files to be inserted in the DB using SQLLDR.

The point I'm facing right now, I need to insert these data into several tables, and this tables are related to each other. That's means, If I insert a person into "Person_table" I will need the Primary Key generated by a database sequence to insert the "Address, Phone, email, etc." into other table, so I do not know how to get the primary keys generated in the first insert via SQLLDR.

I'm not sure sure yet if SQLLDR is my best way to do this, but I guess It is, because the DBMS is Oracle

Can you guys lead me about how could I do what I explained you guys I need to do? any suggestion is welcome and well received. It does not matter if your suggestions are not about how to do this with SQLLDR.

I'm a kind of stuck at this point right now, I really appreciate the help you could give me.

Comment: There is definetely something wrong - either with java implementation or with statistics. If it is really 3000 records for 2 hours (not 30mio) then I suggest to debug java application and find a bottle neck. SQLLDR is able to upload many columns file of 12+ mio records for 5 minutes (my experience).

Comment: Thank you so much by your answer @MaximBorunov. Defintely There was something wrong in the java application. The team who started this project was comsuming too many resources caused by performing recurrent "Select" sentences to the DB before every "Insert". I'm on my way of debugging and trying to solve as much as I can. 

PD: Definitely there's no a way to retrieve the PKs generated by SQLLDR inserts? SQLLDR is incapable to return values isn't it?

Comment: No, SQLLDR is not designed for that. If you still would need to got to SQLLDR then follow the answer @Littlefoot - populate data in some staging tables and then run pl/sql procedure that migrates data into main tables and sets the correct ID for the foreign key columns. But again, the best way is to fix java code.

Answer (score 1):

SQL*Loader can't read native Excel files (at least, as far as I know). Therefore, you'll have to save the result as a CSV file.

As you need to manipulate foreign key constraints, consider switching to **external tables** feature - basically, the background is still SQL*Loader, but you can write (PL/)SQL against those files/tables (yes - a CSV file, stored on a hard disk, acts as if it was an Oracle table).

So, you'd "load" one table, populate primary key values, populate another (child) table - possibly into a "temporary" (not necessarily a *global temporary table*) which doesn't have any constraints enabled, populate foreign key values and move data into a "real" target table whose constraints now won't fail.

Possible drawback: CSV files have to reside in a directory that is accessible to the database server, as you'll have to create a *directory* (Oracle object) and grant required privileges (usually *read, write*) to user who will be using it. Directory is usually created on a server itself; if not, you'll have to use UNC while creating it.

Now you have something to read about/research; see if it makes sense to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Littlefoot. Currently the excel file is not being read by SQLLDR, It is being read by my java application which converts every records in the excel file into "inserts". These inserts are being performance within this java software using JDBC Drivers, But It's taking too long inserting the records. So basically, I'm going to modify the source code to generated data files and control files (to be used with SQLLDR) instead performance inserts. Anyways, your solution is valid and I will consider it.

Comment: By all means, 1500 rows in an hour is a *disaster*, you can't work like that. Pure INSERT takes milliseconds to do that, so - there's really something wrong with current approach. I hope you'll manage to improve it!